# Google calendar events after June 7, 2016 are not displayed on the phone

Tags: calendars, google

If I enter a calendar event on June 7, 2016 or earlier it works as expected. If I enter an event on June 8, 2016 or later it briefly appears on the phone then disappears. The event still exists when I check Google calendar on a PC.

I noticed this yesterday and checked this morning to see if the cut-off date moved forward one day but it didn't. I'm in the US in the Eastern Time Zone. The phone is a Lumia 640 and the calendar app version is 1.0.15087.0. My wife has the same phone and sees the same behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug with the calendar app on Windows 10 Mobile. Events created 6 months in advance will not show up. This problem isn't restricted to certain phones or Google calendars. There is an issue submitted in the Windows Feedback app for this problem, which you can vote on.

Comment: Well that sucks. Now that I understand the problem I was able to search for it but haven't located the feedback issue to upvote yet. At least I was right when I told my wife "it's probably a bug and they won't fix it."

Comment: It comes up for me by filtering feedback by "Apps & Games" > "Outlook Calendar" > "Problems" then searching "Events after June 8 disappear." There are actually quite a few submissions that seem to all be describing the same issue. Hopefully they'll fix it soon.

Comment: I'm on 8.1 an the feedback app doesn't show up in the store. Is there a website I can use?

Comment: Oops, my bad. Must be an issue there, too. Unfortunately I don't think there is. The uservoice site is going to or already has been taken down.